# Broadcast Receiver not working in Oppo,Mi and some other phones when application is closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to detect incoming sms, for that I have created Broadcast Receiver to listen to the incoming sms.
It works perfectly when the app is in the Foreground.But when I close the app from the recent apps then on some phones like **Oppo and xiaomi** the **Receiver stopped working** and is killed.

Below is the code I have implemented:

**SmsReceiver.java**

```
   public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    SmsMessage currentMessage;

    public SmsReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, " reciever called ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            //SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            } else {
                currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }

            String sender = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

            if (sender.contains("HP-CRAZND")) {

                String messageBody = currentMessage.getMessageBody();

                if (messageBody.toString() != null || !messageBody.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Intent ii = new Intent(context, MyService.class);

                    ii.putExtra("s", sender);
                    ii.putExtra("m", messageBody);
                    context.startService(ii);
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

I have added the receiver as below

```
           <receiver
                android:name="saiinfotech.sms.SmsReceiver">
                <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

Comment: Closing an Alarm app from recent list in Xiaomi phones will prevent a preset alarm from going off. Looks like the custom OS completely prevents all activities of app on force closing.

Comment: yes, that's why i am having problem because of  custom Os used by these Companies for security purposes

Comment: Did anyone get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
enable app in autostart then its working fine 

using kotlin, here two extension function first one get manufacturing detail
second one is to open setting to auto start app

    //call this method to get manufacturing detail of mobile
fun Context.checkManufacturing(): Intent? {
    var intent:Intent?=null
    try {
        intent=Intent()
        val manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER
        if ("xiaomi".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true)) {
            intent?.component = ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity")
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
            return intent
        } else if ("oppo".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true)) {
            intent?.component = ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
            return intent
        } else if ("vivo".equals(manufacturer, ignoreCase = true)) {
            intent?.component = ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity")
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
            return intent
        }

        return null
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.message!!.toast()
        return null

    }
return null
}

/// pass intent here get fron check manufacturing method to open setting

fun Intent.autostart(context: Context){
    context.startActivity(this)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I believe that is not related to manufacturer. One needs a service to do it in background, ongoing, survive activity destroy.

If one needs to do it from time to time, use a **Jobscheduler** with a builder and set Periodic and to persist reboot. `setPersisted(true)`.

By the way, what API in Xiaomi and Oppo?